# CakePHP View change extension

Tags: cakephp

How can I change the extension for CakePHP Views from .ctp to .php

I have seen there is this line in /cake/libs/view.php `var $ext = '.ctp';` that sets the extension but how can I do it from my /app/ folder so it doesn't effect Cake core files.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the extension in your `AppController` with

```
public $ext = '.yourext';
```

Comment: What about multiple extensions like accept both .php and .ctp is that possible?

Comment: You cannot specify multiple extensions, however it seems like there is a fall back to .ctp if no .php file is found. This doesn't work for elements, though (I opened a ticket for this issue).

Answer (score 1):

This is is reply to Cameron's comment regarding the issue of using **multiple** extensions in light of the fact cakephp does not allow you to specify multiple extensions.

I am using [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) for a single site that uses merb, rails2, rails3 and cakephp for different sections of the site. The cake site "receives" mustache files for common layout elements but these templates have a '.mustache' file extension which my cake site will not recognize. My workaround is basically what dhofstet suggests just framed in the context of your specific usecase. In short, create a wrapper that might look something like this:

```
<?
  $tmp = $this->ext;
  $this->ext = '.mustache';
?>
<?= $m->render($this->renderElement('moznav/advanced_header'), array('foo' => $bar)) ?><br />

<? $this->ext = $tmp; ?>
```

When flow returns to the caller, you keep on using your native file extension.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change the extension for CakePHP Views from .ctp to .php
>
> I have seen there is this line in /cake/libs/view.php var $ext =
>   '.ctp'; that sets the extension but how can I do it from my /app/
>   folder so it doesn't effect Cake core files.

example:

- you have view `posts/add.ctp`
- now you rename `add.ctp` into `add.php`
- and then you run `.../posts/add` the message error show:

  > Error: The view for PostsController::add() was not found.

  to your app can understand extention `.php`, you add line public `$ext = '.php'` in `PostsController.php`
- now, you run again .`.posts/add`  => okie, cakephp understand extention `.php`

**Notice**: if you use atrribute `$ext = '.php'` but file view named `.ctp`, cakephp extention `.ctp` will use by default

Answer (score 0):

I found this post because I had the same problem. This is not mentioned in the Predominant TwigView plugin documentation on Github. I'm tired of those documentations that explains only half of things and with which we have to guess the second half. This is a big waste of time that slows down projects pointlessly.