# CakePHP TwigView Plugin Missing View Error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, twig, cakephp-2.4

I am using CakePHP 2.4.2 and [this](https://github.com/predominant/TwigView) plugin by predominant.

I want to use TwigView with CakePHP and found that the plugin above is compatible with CakePHP 2.0. Followed all the installation steps, however, getting the **Missing View** error while executing the script.

My AppController.php

```
<?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $viewClass = 'TwigView.Twig';

}
```

The view's extention is **.tpl**, however, even after adding the Plugin it is still looking for **.ctp** extention.

I have also loaded the plugin in bootstrap.php using

```
CakePlugin::load('TwigView');
define('TWIG_VIEW_CACHE', APP . 'tmp');
```

Any Idea what could go wrong.

Comment: There is an open pull request that sounds like it will fix your issue: https://github.com/predominant/TwigView/pull/19

Comment: There is no fix needed, see my answer.

Comment: @burzum I think the issue is that the $ext property in the view gets overriden by the one defined in the controller, and that this worked differently when the plugin was written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Controller.html#209-214

Set the Controller::$ext property in your app controller to "tpl" and your're done.

Searching before asking is also always a good idea, see [CakePHP View change extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634361/cakephp-view-change-extension)