# CakePHP not recognizing Twig Layouts

Tags: php, cakephp, twig

I'm new to CakePHP and I need to integrate Twig for a project. First I installed the **TwigView** plugin (https://github.com/predominant/TwigView) and tried to follow the small set of instructions.

### Installation

#### Plugin sources

I cloned the plugin repository in **/app/Plugin/**. A folder **TwigView** is created.

#### Twig sources

I placed Twig sources under **/app/Plugin/TwigView/Vendor/** in a folder named **Twig**

### Configuration

I added this to my **/app/Config/bootstrap.php**

```
CakePlugin::loadAll();
```

and this to **AppController**

```
public $viewClass = 'TwigView.Twig';
```

I also granted *write* privileges to everybody in **/app/Plugin/TwigView/tmp/views**

### Problem 1

The application keeps asking for **.ctp** files, and I need to use my **.tpl** templates. I tried adding this in **AppController**

```
public $layout = 'default.tpl';
```

But it will complain, saying that it can't find **default.tpl.ctp**

### Problem 2

How can I pass parameters to the twig templates from Cake controllers?

Comment: If it's still searching for `.ctp` files, then TwigView isn't being set. The `Twig` view class sets the extensions to `.tpl` for you, so no need to change the `$layout` var. More info required to answer. I.e., ensure the plugin is running, make sure it's using the view class, etc. Pepper some debug statements in the plugin and your bootstrap to make sure everything's running right. Show us a basic controller / action that should be using it and make sure the view class isn't being reset somewhere.

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138038/cakephp-twigview-plugin-missing-view-error?rq=1